# Anti-bot techniques

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php5

I want to do some research on anti-bot techniques for my web application. I am aware of Captcha, but want to explore some other techniques. Especially, I want users to visit all the pages before they fill a request form.

I am using LAMP.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about things like comment spam? Is it for a forum, blog or other community based web application?

Answer (score 1):

lighttpd has a Trigger before Download module that requires a user to hit particular pages to add the IP to the hash that allowed access to the protected resource.  There was a company that wrote an apache module called TrafficGuardian that did the same thing.

Another method would be to maintain a session hash that kept track of the resources viewed, and your protected resource checks to see that the hash has all values set.

Many different ways to do it.